# Pandas/SQL co-occurrence count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have the following table/data frame:

```
d = {'store': ['s1', 's1', 's2', 's2',], 'product': ['a', 'c', 'a', 'c']}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


print(df)
    store  product
0     s1      a                 
1     s1      c                     
3     s2      a                  
4     s2      c
```

I would like to find, for each pair of products the number of times they co-occur in a store.

Since the data is **very large** (5M rows and about 50K individual products & 20K individual stores) and there are many potential co-occurrence pairs, I would just like to get the top n (example: 10) co-occurrences for each product and the count of the cooccurrence. The example result is below:

```
    product_1  product_2     cooccurrence_count
0      a           c                  2 
1      c           a                  2
```

**An effective and efficient solution in SQL instead of pandas would also be acceptable**

Comment: Are the products in each store unique?

Comment: No the products are not unique to a store, the vast majority of them will occur in multiple stores at the same time. @AndrejKesely

Comment: so for example product 'a' may occur in 5,000 stores

Comment: But can product `a` be in store `s1` multiple times, for example?

Comment: sorry did not understand what you meant originally, Yes a product can only occur in a store a single time, so in this sense they are unique to each store and cannot be duplicated within a single store. @AndrejKesely

Comment: There's no magic. You either have to make a ~60GB table of cooccurrences and their counts and query that.  Or do severa scans through the database for the amount of cooccurrences that fit in memory.  Scotts solution is probably your best bet with a couple of tweaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only because the question is well written and it seemed like a nice puzzle, here's some magic.

Potentially you'll have to store a lot of data, so you need to compress the frame as much as possible and do several passes through the base. If the database contains not primitive objects, convert those into integers, if you do multiprocessing, the dataframe will be copied into subprocesses, so keeping it contents small helps.

The runtime depends on the length of the dataframe but also on the number of unique stores, unique products and the size of a chunk of pairs to count. Spreading the work to many subprocesses can speed up things but there is constant cost to all the functions which will accumulate. For example, pandas' own methods will run faster on a single ten thousand rows dataframe than on a dozen of thousand row frames. And when you're running nested calls on sub dataframes of unpredictable size things get complicated. You'll probably have to experiment a bit to find a chunksize with optimal speed\memory usage.

Test runtimes with smaller numbers first. Including less shops and products. That being said, this is not a quick task. On high end machine it completes in about ten minutes.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'store':np.random.randint(0,int(2e4),int(5e6)),
  'product':np.random.randint(0,int(5e4),int(5e6))
  }).sort_values('store')

products = df['product'].unique()
N, chunksize, Ntop = len(products), int(1e4), 200
dtype = np.min_scalar_type(max(products.max(),N))
df = df.astype(dtype)

def store_cats(df):
    df = df.astype('category')
    cats = [df[x].cat.categories for x in df.columns]
    for col in df.columns:
        df[col] = df[col].cat.codes
    return df, cats    
def restore_cats(summary,cats):
    for col in ['product_x','product_y']:
        summary[col] = pandas.Categorical.from_codes(summary[col], cats)

def subsets(n = chunksize):
    n = int(n)
    res = [frozenset(products[i:i+n]) for i in range(0,N,n)]
    info = 'In total there will be {:.1E} pairs, per pass {:.1E} will be checked, thats up to around {} mb per pass, {} passes'
    print(info.format((N**2),(n*N),(n*N*3*8/1e6),len(res)))
    return res

def count(df,subset):
    res = df.merge(df,on = 'store')\
        .query('(product_x < product_y) and product_x in @subset')\
        .groupby(['product_x','product_y'])\
        .count()\
        .astype(dtype)\
        .reset_index()
    return res 
def one_pass(gr,subset):
    per_group = gr.apply(count,subset)
    total_counts = per_group.sort_values(['product_x','product_y'])\
        .groupby(['product_x','product_y'])\
        .agg('sum')\
        .sort_values('store',ascending=False)[:Ntop]\
        .copy().reset_index()
    return total_counts
def merge_passes(dfs):
    res = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
    res = res.append(res.rename(columns={'product_x':'product_y','product_y':'product_x'}),ignore_index=True)
    res = res.sort_values('store',ascending=False)[:Ntop]
    return res

from concurrent.futures import as_completed, ProcessPoolExecutor as Pool

gr = df.groupby('store',as_index = False)
def worker(subset):
    return one_pass(gr,subset)
def run_progress(max_workers=2,chunksize=chunksize):
    from tqdm.auto import tqdm 
    with Pool(max_workers = max_workers) as p:
        futures = [p.submit(worker,subset) for subset in subsets(chunksize)]
        summaries = [x.result() for x in tqdm(as_completed(futures),total=len(futures))]
        return merge_passes(summaries)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
df.merge(df, on=['store']).query('product_x != product_y')\
  .groupby(['product_x','product_y'], as_index=False).count()\
  .rename(columns={'store':'cooccurence_count'})
```

Output:

```
  product_x product_y  cooccurence_count
0         a         c                  2
1         c         a                  2
```

With very large dataframes this might cause a memory problem.

---

Maybe this might help with memory useage:

```
from functools import reduce
l = {}
for n, g in df.groupby('store'):
    l[n] = g.merge(g, how='cross').query('product_x != product_y')\
            .groupby(['product_x', 'product_y']).count()

reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l.values())
```

Let's chop it up by 'store'

Comment: Unable to allocate 88.2 GiB for an array with shape (11832115817,) and data type int64

Answer (score 2):

Try with `pd.crosstab` then `dot` and `value_counts`

```
s = pd.crosstab(df['store'],df['product'])
out = s.dot(s.columns+',').value_counts()
out
a,c,    2
```

Or we do

```
s = pd.crosstab(df['store'],df['product'])
s = s.T.dot(s).astype(float)
s.values[np.triu_indices(len(s))]=np.nan
s.stack()
product  product
c        a          2.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: is the a more efficient/faster way to do this? I have a dataset with 5M rows and about 50K individual products & 20K individual stores, I tried your method but even after hours it could not run to completion.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't know how this will perform on a set that large, but here's a sql option:

```
-- test data
CREATE TABLE #T (
    store varchar(10), 
    product varchar(5)
    )

INSERT INTO #T (store, product)
VALUES
('s1','a'),
('s1','c'),
('s2','a'),
('s2','c')


-- the part you really want:
SELECT TOP 10 
      prod1.product_1
    , prod2.product_2
    , COUNT(*) cooccurrence_count
FROM 
    (SELECT product product_1, store from #t) prod1
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT product product_2, store from #t) prod2
    ON prod1.store = prod2.store AND prod1.product_1 <> prod2.product_2
GROUP BY prod1.product_1, prod2.product_2
ORDER BY cooccurrence_count desc
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the biggest issues you're facing is how to make such a big dataframe in memory, the ideal solution is using sparse matrices

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import scipy.sparse as sp
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
d = {'store': ['s1', 's1', 's2', 's2',], 'product': ['a', 'c', 'a', 'b']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['count']=1
store_c = CategoricalDtype(sorted(df.store.unique()), ordered=True)
product_c = CategoricalDtype(sorted(df['product'].unique()), ordered=True)

row = df.store.astype(store_c).cat.codes
col = df['product'].astype(product_c).cat.codes
sparse_matrix = csr_matrix((df["count"], (row, col)), \
                           shape=(store_c.categories.size, product_c.categories.size))

sparse_matrix.todense()  ## don't do this, your matrix won't fit in memory
>>matrix([[1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 0]], dtype=int64)

new_matrix=sparse_matrix.T*sparse_matrix  ## this will count the numbre of cooccurance 

new_matrix.todense()  ## don't do this, your matrix wont fit in memory
>>matrix([[2, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

now the new_matrix would be a 50k x 50k sized sparse matrix which would have the required calculation

```
x,y,val = sp.find(new_matrix)    ## just need to find all non zero values and convert to pandas dataframe

val_df = pd.DataFrame(zip(x,y,val) ,columns=['product1','product2','common_count'])
val_df

>>
product1    product2    common_count
0   0   0   2
1   1   0   1
2   2   0   1
3   0   1   1
4   1   1   1
5   0   2   1
6   2   2   1
```

since zip is a generator, it should not take much time
Later you can convert back the numbers 0,1,2,.. to their respective product names using `product_c` variable

Try this and do let me know the time it takes to process this much