# Pairwise value counts based on category column in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, cluster-analysis

I have datasets which look like
[image: Data]

Each dataset corresponds to output of a clustering algorithm. Now I want to calculate, Number of times any pair of Names are occurring together

**Example:**

Pair John & Katie are occurring together in all datasets so their score would 3

Pair Paul & Ruth are occurring together in 2 datasets so their score would 2

**Expected output:**

[image: output]

I have tried taking outer joins but the code doesn't seem to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68061201/pandas-sql-co-occurrence-count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ease of reference and to avoid errors due to differing names, I would first concatenate the three dataframes into one, so that it looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John', 'Katie', 'Paul', 'Ruth', 'Emily', 'Monica'],
                   'Category1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
                   'Category2': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C'],
                   'Category3': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']})
df
```

```
    Name    Category1   Category2   Category3
0   John    A           A           A
1   Katie   A           A           A
2   Paul    B           B           A
3   Ruth    B           C           A
4   Emily   C           B           B
5   Monica  C           C           B
```

You can use the `combinations` function from the `itertools` module to get all possible pairs of names, as well as the corresponding pairs of categories. This is most conveniently done within a dictionary comprehension, so that you can directly create a new dataframe from it.

Then you just have to count the number of category pairs in each row for which both categories are the same.

```py
from itertools import combinations

df_pairs = pd.DataFrame({col: combinations(df[col], 2) for col in df.columns})
df_pairs['Score'] = df_pairs.apply(lambda row: sum([int(pair[0] == pair[1])
                                                    for pair in row[1:]]), axis=1)
df_pairs
```

```
    Name            Category1   Category2   Category3   Score
0   (John, Katie)   (A, A)      (A, A)      (A, A)      3
1   (John, Paul)    (A, B)      (A, B)      (A, A)      1
2   (John, Ruth)    (A, B)      (A, C)      (A, A)      1
3   (John, Emily)   (A, C)      (A, B)      (A, B)      0
4   (John, Monica)  (A, C)      (A, C)      (A, B)      0
5   (Katie, Paul)   (A, B)      (A, B)      (A, A)      1
6   (Katie, Ruth)   (A, B)      (A, C)      (A, A)      1
7   (Katie, Emily)  (A, C)      (A, B)      (A, B)      0
8   (Katie, Monica) (A, C)      (A, C)      (A, B)      0
9   (Paul, Ruth)    (B, B)      (B, C)      (A, A)      2
10  (Paul, Emily)   (B, C)      (B, B)      (A, B)      1
11  (Paul, Monica)  (B, C)      (B, C)      (A, B)      0
12  (Ruth, Emily)   (B, C)      (C, B)      (A, B)      0
13  (Ruth, Monica)  (B, C)      (C, C)      (A, B)      1
14  (Emily, Monica) (C, C)      (B, C)      (B, B)      2
```